# Find a solution set to a system of vectors that equals the span

Tags: linear-algebra

For the system [2x-4y+z+w=0 and x+3w=0] find some vectors {v1,..,vk} such that the solution set to the system equals the span {v1,..,vk}

Okay here we go! I think I understand that the span of a set of vectors is the set of all linear combinations of a set of vectors and if a,b are elements of R then we can write the span as a(2,-4,1,1)+b(1,0,0,3) and together as (2a+b,-4a,a,a+3b)

For the solution set I did the Gauss Jordan and got x=-3w and y=(z/4)-(5w/4).

However my understanding is very shaky and not really sure how to procede. I was thinking of equating a&b with x&y but don't really know why I would. All help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After performing Gaussian elimination, you found that there were two basic variables ($x$ and $y$) that could be expressed in terms of two free variables ($z$ and $w$). This tells us that the basis should have dimension equal to the number of free variables (two). Indeed, an arbitrary vector that satisfies the given system must have the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z \\ w
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
-3w \\ \tfrac{1}{4}z - \tfrac{5}{4}w \\ z \\ w
\end{bmatrix}
= 
z\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ \tfrac{1}{4} \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
+
w\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\ -\tfrac{5}{4} \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Scaling the vectors in order to eliminate the fractions, the desired subspace is:
$$
\text{span}\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 4 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
-12 \\ -5 \\ 0 \\ 4
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$